# Mac suddenly boots from dead ssd?

Tags: mac, ssd

So about a month back i got the question mark folder and couldnt asee the disk in diskutil list so i assumed it died and started working from a sd card but today it suddenly booted from the ssd that i assumes was dead with all the data in it.So after I used the mac from the internal ssd I shut it down and had dissapeared again.

I would like to know if this is a problem with the ssd or the macbook itself?

I forgot to mention the macbook is a macbook pro mid 2014

Comment: Had you tried running Diagnostic test? (press and hold D on startup)

Comment: The only error i get is VDH002  

Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: Then it's probably a hardware problem. Had you tried putting the MacBook in target disk mode and connecting it to another MacBook to see whether you can find the disk in `diskutil list`?

Comment: i unfortunately do not have access to another mac and the ssd does not appear in diskutil list but it suddenly booted from it with all the data today but then after i finished using it and shut it down it doesnt boot from it again and does not show up in diskutil list.

Comment: And i would also like to mention that i didnt use the macbook at all for the past two days before it booted from the ssd again

Comment: I have been using an sd card with macos since last month and i did diskutil list from that without using target disk mode

Answer (score 2):

It’s going to be hard to know unless you isolate the failure by replacing a part and seeing if that fixes things.

- https://support.apple.com/kb/SP703

The PCIe based storage drives can be swapped, so that upgrade might let you know. Have you booted to recovery and tried to make a backup? Once you have your files, you can run disk utility and disk information from recovery to see if the storage is detected or has errors.

If you are good with small repairs, and can ground yourself properly, reseating the storage would be the first thing a technician tries. Then they apple run apple service diagnostics a second time if the first run had no errors.

- https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/559054/Random+freezes+&+VDH002+%22There+may+be+an+issue+with+a+storage+device%22

Things this could be is a corrupt EFI (zero the drive, [install a clean OS - Mojave or newer if possible and fully patch the system, including firmware updates), bad cables, bad drive](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2015+SSD+Replacement/48251), bad controller or logic board.

It’s not the OS since the system would show the drive even if the OS was gone or corrupt each and every time you tried to boot the Mac from internet recovery or an external media.

Comment: I was able to boot from the ssd again and i did the first aid and got several warnings of : found orphan dstream id object (id 506740, refcnt 1)